# Sitecore and eWay SDK integration

Tags: c#, .net, payment-gateway, sitecore8, eway

The eWay SDK uses both automapper and newtonsoft .dll's - I am currently trying to create an "eWaywrapper" project within my solution which uses the eWay SDK.

For some reason I get runtime errors from eWay complaining about the wrong version of libraries. The bin for the project contains the correct .dll's but its almost like the eWay SDK is looking at the parent bin folder which houses all the sitecore binaries.

I figured this probably isn't a unique problem, as surely other integrations use different .dll versions that conflict with Sitecores.

Has anyone got a work around for this scenario like compiling library DLL's into a project, or creating a service for the eWay stuff or something else along those lines. Thanks.